# WCF Service Contract not generated correctly with IsOneWay Attribute

Tags: vb.net, wcf, contract

I have following ServiceBehaviour on my service:

```
<ServiceBehavior(IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults:=True), _
AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode:=Activation.AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Required)> _
```

When i add a Sub/void method to my service all my contracts are generated correctly. But when i change my OperationContract to IsOneWay:

```
<OperationContract(IsOneWay:=True)> _
```

In this case if i add my service all the other Functions are generated as void/sub methods.
And there seem to be even more issues with generated WCF proxy.

Am i missing something here?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Can you give an example of what you expect? By definition any method marked as `IsOneWay` cannot return any data to the caller and is therefore a void method.

Comment: @ErnieL : indeed the IsOneWay method should be generated as Void method. But my other function with a return type are also generated with a void return type. And they should have concrete types.